# Wordpress: Have no idea how to change the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, navbar

first off I am sorry if my question is very noobish. I am willing to bet it is probably a very simple solution and maybe other ones out there, but as I can word it, I haven't yet found a solution. Anyway, on to it!

I am trying to develop my first website on wordpress. I have chosen this theme to do so: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/themes/urban-bold/

For some reason however, the navigation bar came out completely different from the template and I absolutely hate it!

Here is what it currently looks like: [image]

For some reason the logo or website title just goes on top of the navbar, instead of off to the side like the template, which is what I was going for! Whenever I look for answers in previously posted questions, it seems that I have to edit the CSS or something, which is yet another thing I have no idea how to do it from a Wordpress template. I have downloadd a plugin called Simple Custom CSS, but I am still clueless where to go from there. It's all been so overwhelming to learn this...

I am quite lost here and would really appreciate some insight on how to make the navbar follow the format of the template (logo or title off to the left, with the menu/page buttons off to the right).

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1040px) { 
    #logo.full { float:left !important; }
}
```

to your theme css file through FTP

> /wp-content/themes/urban-bold/style.css

or from Admin area > Design menu > Editor > select style.css

Comment: Thank you very much! This did work nicely.
However, the page lost is not completely responsive anymore. Is there any way to solve that or is it a whole other series of complications? Thanks!